# Fade out CCSprite that's tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'd like to fade out a sprite once it's tapped for an iOS game I'm making with cocos2d. Currently, the sprite spawns and it's declared like so:

```
@implementation GameScene
{
    CCSprite *_shapeSprite;
}
```

and then I have one appear every 0.2 seconds within an `addShape:` method

```
- (void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self schedule:@selector(addShape:) interval:0.2];
}
```

However, I'd like to make it so when one of the shapes are tapped then only the one that has been tapped disappears. So far, I've got this:

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    _shapeSprite.opacity = 0;
}
```

However that simply removes the last shape that's spawned and not the one that's tapped - can someone please point me in the right direction here please?

Comment: store all sprite in array, when screen touched then compare if position of touch is inside any sprite's boundingBox. If yes then that sprite touched and do whatever u want.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, be sure to have self.userInteractionEnabled = YES; in init

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint touchLoc = [touch locationInNode:self];

    // detect Sprite
    for (CCSprite *mySprite in self.children) {

        float distance = pow(mySprite.position.x - touchLoc.x, 2) + pow(mySprite.position.y - touchLoc.y, 2);
        distance = sqrt(distance);
        if (distance <= 60) { //60 is radius from sprite center, change it
            // do something with this sprite
            mySprite.opacity = 0;

        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do the trick, the sprites still aren't make opaque. Also, Xcode throws out a warning about how the control reaches the end of a non-void function?

Comment: Wich version of cocos2d are you using, v2 or v3?